# Создать один установщик для Web-службы и приложения

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2010, install

Такая ситуация: В одном проекте имею Web-службу (ставится как сайт в IIS) и простое WinForm приложение. Нужно создать установщик. Сделал проект WebSetup. Работает. Но вот взять и добавить возможность выбора куда ставить приложение нельзя (устанавливается в ту же папку, что и Web-служба). Нет возможности добавить соответствующую форму в список User Interface. Ну и если сделать обычный установщик (проект Setup), то с установкой службы проблемы... Как можно создать установщик, который и службу мне поставит и приложение даст выбрать куда установить? Используя только стандартные средства Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Боюсь, стандартными средствами не получится...

Comment: Какие проблемы у Вас возникают с установкой службы?

Comment: При установке web-службы отдельно - никаких. А вот вместе поставить не получается. Могу создать Web установщик и тогда у меня не будет возможности выбирать куда ставить приложение. Оно поставится в папку со службой. Могу создать обычный установщик и в него добавить проект Web-службы, но тогда она не будет установлена в IIS.